Comma before "and" when listing only 2 nouns

Mass tourism can lead to overcrowding, and pollution due to increased transportation and waste generated by tourists.

If the part "due to increased..." only adds meaning to the second noun "pollution," can a comma be used before "and"? If so, is it mandatory?

A way to simplify the statement is to move the elements (unless these are intended to follow a particular order): Mass tourism can leading to overcrowding, waste generated by tourists and pollution due to increased transportation.

@RonaldSole I think "pollution" stems from both increased transportation and waste, making your suggestion different in meaning from the original sentence.

@AnIELTSLearner If that was the author's intention, I should amend my suggestion: "Mass tourism can lead to overcrowding and to pollution arising (both) from waste generated by tourists and increased overcrowding."

It's optional, but I think most would use it to avoid ambiguity over what  "due to..." qualifies.

Whoever voted you down for that answer is a fool.
